# How can I get the value of an input field?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value of my input field:

```js
var test = $(".data[data-select='true']").find($('.price').val());
                            
alert(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<tr class="data" data-select="true"><td><input class="price" value="12,00" type="text"></td></tr>

<tr class="data" data-select="false"><td><input class="price" value="23,00" type="text"></td></tr>
```

The output I expect is `12,00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `.val()` on jquery object of input element:

```
 var test = $(".data[data-select='true']").find('.price').val();
```

```js
   var test = $(".data[data-select='true']").find('.price').val();
                            
alert(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr class="data" data-select="true"><td><input class="price" value="12,00" type="text"></td></tr>

<tr class="data" data-select="false"><td><input class="price" value="23,00" type="text"></td></tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Your snippet output is "undefined"

Comment: TR tags were ignored by browser as there was no table element wrapping them. should be good now.

Answer (score 1):

You should stick out val() from find() selector.

```
var test = $(".data[data-select='true']").find('.price').val();
```